# brace initialized function pointer array: invalid conversion from 'void (*(*)())()' to 'void (*)()'

Tags: c++, c, arrays, arduino, function-pointers

In my arduino sketch I need an array of function pointers with the signature `void foo()`.
I'm using the `ino` command line utillity on linux (which uses avr-g++ under the hood).

However I'm getting a very strange error while defining the array.

error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void (* (*)())()’ to ‘void (*)()’
```

in this piece of code

```
void (*mode_setup[])(void) = {
    &show_time_setup,
    &set_time_setup,    
    &set_alarm_setup,
    &set_date_setup // <-- generates 3 identical error on this line
};
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, since... `int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` ..is perfectly valid, and `void (*foo)(void)` is the syntax for function pointer.

what am I missing?

**edit: NEVERMIND IM STUPID
the functions were not void foo(), but fptr foo() [fptr=function pointer typedef]
sincere appologies for wasting peoples time**

Comment: Are the `&`s supposed to be there for a function pointer?

Comment: I think you need `(*mode_setup)[]`.

Comment: One or two judicious typedefs would have been helpful here.

Comment: (Because [it seems okay](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*mode_setup[]%29%28void%29))

Comment: What is the signature of `set_date_setup`?

Comment: It appears that `show_time_setup` et al are functions that return function pointers, not `void`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas void set_date_setup(), I meant to imply that in the first paragraph.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/ndfqxs). The problem must be in the code you haven't shown. Most likely, one or more of these four functions are not in fact like `void f()`

Comment: In addition to my original comment: Whenever using function pointers, a typedef certianly makes the code A LOT more readable - `typedef void (*setup_func)(void);` and `setup_func mode_setup[] = { ... };` would be my choice of solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your error message with this code

```
void (*foo())() {}
void (*arr[])(void) = { &foo };
```

So it looks like the signature of the function(s) is not what you think it is. An array to hold a pointer to `foo` would need to be declared like this:

```
void (*(*arr[])())(void) = {
    &foo
};
```

If I were you, I'd consider typedefs...